# pcl::io::loadPCDFile Could not find file 'gArBaGe'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, point-cloud-library

I'm using a really simple code example I found in a [tutorial](https://saturncloud.io/blog/setting-up-point-cloud-library-with-visual-studio/#step-5-write-code).

When I try to use the `pcl::io::loadPCDFile` no metter how I try to parameterize it, but ofc I give it valid path with valid point cloud, it always logs:

> [pcl::PCDReader::read] Could not find file '(ў}~═'.

or a similar 5 character long garbage. I assume the string gets corrupted somehow but the worriing things are:

1. I already used the [recommended way](https://pointclouds.org/downloads/) to instal PCL using vcpkg package manager,
2. I tryed with the installer too downloaded from github: [PCL-1.13.1-AllInOne-msvc2022-win64.exe](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases)

In both cases I experienced the same issue, and for an extra fun fact, the `pcl::io::savePCDFile` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I mixed up 2 ways to install the lib which led to UB.
Initially I followed the instructions of [this](https://saturncloud.io/blog/setting-up-point-cloud-library-with-visual-studio/#setting-up-pcl-with-visual-studio) installation guide, followed the link to download PCL and it led me to [this](https://pointclouds.org/downloads/) download page. I installed vcpkg and after that I used the installation command:

```
vcpkg install pcl
```

After the installation I followed the original setup guide and I started to add the things to the VS project and this was incorrect and unnecessary.

Instead I found the [this](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started#:%7E:text=Installing%20vcpkg%20is%20a%20two,installed%20from%20the%20command%20line.) guide, and the solution within what was the following command right after the installation proces finishes.

```
vcpkg integrate install
```

This will automatically setup the include and lib configurations for VS, and in the project properties there is no need for further configuration.